# breeze: BMEAN sample issue

Tags: breeze

I gave that project a try and it looks great... but I can't run it.

I've started both the mongodb and express servers and if I browse to `http://my-server:3000/breeze/zza/Products`, I get the list products so all is fine with routing and db connection.

However if I browse to `http://my-server:3000` I get a 404. Seems like there is no redirection to index.html

If I browse to `http://my-server:3000/breeze/zza/metadata`, then the code :

```
fs.existsSync(filname)
```

fails because the file is not found. It's looking into `Zza.ExpressServer/public/app/metadata.js`

I'm not sure what zza.expressServer is ? Because the file is actualy in `Zza-Node-Mongo/public/app/metadata.js`.

Any idea what's wrong ?

Comment: ok, I got the metadata to work, I had to change the value of var serverBase to the actual path of my project. However I'm still not getting any UI to load. That's because the Index view is not found. There is no routes defined to redirect to index.html, so I'm wondering how this app is supposed to work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it to work. Browsing to `http://my-server:3000`still does not work. But browsing to `http://my-server:3000/Index.html` does work

At first I was typing index.html instead of Index.html, and since I'm running the site on a linux machine, the case does matter... 
Same for the css and scripts folder. In the code it's Scripts and Content, but the folders are named scripts and content, so I had to change that too.

Works great now, great sample so kudos to breeze team

**EDIT**

to redirect all routes to index.html:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {

   res.sendfile('./public/Index.html'); 

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I am also currently working with this sample app.  I did not run into any of the issues you're describing.  I followed the sample's readme.md file.  I also wondered how the index.html file is called.  My gut feeling is that since the index.html file is in the public folder, Express looks for that by default.  In other Express apps I've built, there was a specific route that pointed "/" to my index.html file.

For example, 
    app.get('/', routes.index); //points to index.js which has

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
};
```

which loads index.html

But, I don't see that happening in the Zza sample.  I also found out the hard way that the UI wouldn't load when I had something else running on port 3000.  I'm new to Node.js and I was testing a few apps and since there was another sample app running on port 3000, this prevented my Zza sample from running.  I realize that I haven't answered your question or solved your problem, but, at least you know that the sample, out-of-the box should run.

Comment: I'm new to Express too, but like you, other SPA I've seen were all using a route to redirect to index.html. I really don't see how it works here. Did you not have to change the value of serverBase in order to get the metadata to work ? Anyway, thanks for the feedback, that's useful to know it works for others, although I'm feeling even more frustrated now :)

Comment: I'm glad you got it running.  You're on Linux and I'm on Windows 8.1.  I didn't have to alter anything.  I had to start Node with the server.js file and then navigate to http://localhost:3000 and the Index.html file automatically rendered.  You could very well be onto something regarding "routing case sensitivity".  I recall that there is a way to turn that on | off in Express.  I found this, but, I don't know the exact Express command: case sensitive routing Enable case sensitivity, disabled by default, treating "/Foo" and "/foo" as the same.